# Option to elevate priveleges in Ubuntu GNOME for file copy

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, gnome, gksudo

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 (GNOME) and I'm just copying over certain files from my backup which is on a Windows computer. The backup includes:

- A few scripts in `/usr/bin`
- A number of websites in `/var/www`
- A couple of startup scripts in `/etc/init.d`

I'm comfortable using the command line, but for this kind of one-off quick copy I'd rather use the GUI. I know I can `gksudo nautilus` but this is a bit cumbersome, loses any personal GNOME customisations, and keeps elevated privileges until the process is terminated.

What I'd like is that when I attempt a file copy that currently gives a permissions error, I get an option to temporarily elevate privileges. Can anyone help?

TIA

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about such thing. You could do this with checking the error message and then prompting for password. However this is a modification of Nautilus, not a simple addon, since I don't think Nautilus supports such addons. (Guess you could write this on a code freelancer page. You pay x$ if someone writes a nautilus fork with this feature. Well.. not a long term solution.)

Basically you could write a .sh script for the backup and run that with sudo, OR simply use `sudo cp -R` ... something like that. (Rsync?)

Comment: Thanks, was hoping something already existed. I'm happy with command line-based approaches but was looking for a convenient GUI system for one-off unpredictable copies.

Comment: One could write such an app easily... but... that would be really "FLOSS-like".. you know when they start an app , give out 0.1, let it die.

Comment: not entirely with you?!

Comment: You mean? :-/ ... (Seriously. If one can launch sudo cp or gksu , whatever, why would write an app? Why add MOAR bloat to the nautilus which is also "feel like sloooooow doooown"? Maybe if the permission problem would come in a way where we can intercept it with an app. (Means ALSO addig moar bloat to a system which is already slower than any other OS out there. Which we can't really let happen. (I'm an LXDE user/insider before you start thinking.. :))

Comment: If I remember clearly there were some backup apps which supports that moving here and there. However, don't know if they support this dialog. (Like robocopy gui on Windows)

Comment: with you! I don't know if it could be gracefully handled with GNOME's architecture...  but a feature like this doesn't _have to_ be handled in a bloaty way... I reckon!

Comment: Well... you just have to buy Novell or Canonical and thar u go. Gnome support, bugtracker is way too chaotic.